# Automated property cannot be assigned to - read only

Tags: c#

I'm implementing an interface with a model that has an automated property.

Trying to modify the value of the automated property at the implementation results in `"Property or indexer 'KeyValuePair<int, int>.Key' cannot be assigned to -- it is readonly"`

The implementation:

```
    public class CartDB : ICartDB
    {
        Cart Cart = new Cart(); 

        public CartDB()
        {
            Cart.Items = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        }

        public void EditItem(Dictionary<int, int> NewQuantity)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < NewQuantity.Keys.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> newEntry in NewQuantity)
                {
                    Cart.Items
                        .Where(cartItem => cartItem.Key == newEntry.Key).First().Key = newEntry.Key;
                }
            }
        }
```

The Cart model:

```
public class Cart
    {
        public Dictionary<int, int> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

The interface:

```
public interface ICartDB
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> GetCart();
        // Add, delete may receive many items or just one.
        void DeleteItems(List<int> Items);
        // The key is item id while value is the quantity of itemid
        void AddItems(Dictionary<int, int> Items);
        void EditItem(Dictionary<int, int> NewQuantity);

    }
```

EditItem()'s purpose is to only change the value of a specific key in a dictionary which is the automated property received from the model Cart.

Comment: "readonly" means that the value can only be assigned once in the constructor. But it also has to be assigned in the constructor latest.

Comment: You cannot change the key of an item in the dictionary. You must remove the item from the dictionary and then re-add it with the new key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KeyValuePair is immutable. If you want to change it, create a new one.

```
var oldPair = Cart.Items
    .Where(cartItem => cartItem.Key == newEntry.Key).First();
var newPair = new KeyValuePair<int,int>(newEntry.Key, oldPair.Value);

Cart.Items.Remove(oldPair);
Cart.Items.Add(newPair);
```